# Suppose $f$ is an entire function s.t. $\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_j(z)(f(z))^j=0$ where $p_j(z)$ are non-zero polynomials. Show $f$ is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function that satisfies an equation of the form $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_j(z)(f(z))^j=0$$ where $p_j(z)$ are non-zero polynomials.

Show that $f$ is a polynomial.

We claim that if $f$ is entire but it is not a polynomial then for any $k\in\mathbb N$ there is a sequence $z_l\to\infty$ for which $z_l^{-k}f(z_l)\to\infty$.

As $f$ is entire, it has a Taylor series representation at $z=0$, namely, $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n.$$ But if it is not a polynomial, then we have $a_i\neq 0$ for infinitely many $a_i$. This means for all $k\in\mathbb N$, the function $$z^{-k}f(z)$$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$. By the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, the values $z^{-k}f(z)$ approach every complex number as $z\to\infty$. This means that for every $k\in\mathbb N$ there is a sequence $\{z_l\}$ for which $z^{-k}f(z_l)\to\infty$ as $l\to\infty$.

Now suppose that $f$ satisfies $$p_1(z)(f(z))+\cdots+p_{m-1}(z)(f(z))^{m-1}+p_m(z)(f(z))^m=0.$$

Any hints on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the maximum degree of $p_1,..p_m$ to be $N$; this means that there is $R>1$ s.t. $|p_k(z)| < |z|^{N+1}$ for $|z|>R, k=1,..m$.

Assume $f$ not a polynomial; since then $f(z)z^{-N-2}$ is not bounded at infinity, we can pick $|z_n| \to \infty, |z_n| >R>1, |f(z_n)| > |z_n|^{N+2}, n \ge 1$. Also since $p_m$ is not the sero polynomial, there is $c>0, R_1>R, |p_m(z)|>c$ for all $|z|>R_1$, so in particular wlog we can assume $|p_m(z_n)|>c$ for all $n \ge 1$, while obviously we have $|f(z_n)|>|z_n|^{N+2}>1$ by our choices

Then dividing the equation:

$p_1(z_n)(f(z_n))+\cdots+p_{m-1}(z_n)(f(z_n))^{m-1}=-p_m(z_n)(f(z_n))^m$.

by $z_n^{N+1}(f(z_n))^{m-1}$ (which we know to be at least $|z_n|^{(m-1)(N+2)+N+1}>1$ in absolute value), taking absolute values and using the triangle inequality we get:

$m-1 \ge LHS=RHS>c|z_n| \to \infty$ and that is a contradiction. Done!